# Find and replace spaces by commas in multiple text files after a certain keyword

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a folder with text files that have this structure:

```
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_Mean NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_Std NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_Slope NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_PeriodFreq NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_PeriodAmp NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE dynamics_rms_PeriodEntropy NUMERIC

@DATA
9.749956e-01 2.257056e-01 1.667380e-01 NaN NaN 9.706193e-01
```

I want to use *Sublime Text* to find and replace for all these text files the "space" characters BELOW `@DATA`, but preserving the spaces in the lines starting with `@ATTRIBUTE`.

I have  found a way to select all the spaces in the text file, but I don't know how to select only the ones after `@DATA` and replace them in every file (using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: is there only one line to treat under the `@DATA` line?

Comment: No, there are more lines, a complete text file contains about 300 ATTRIBUTES, and there's one value below DATA for each of them, so there are around 34 lines of space-separated values.

Comment: Yes but for one "@DATA" line, there is only one line to treat, isn't it?

Comment: Below the @DATA line, there will be 34 lines with space separated values so there will be 34 lines to treat.

Comment: And how do you know that following lines are related to the `@DATA` line? is there an empty line at the end or something else (a new @ATTRIBUTE block perhaps)?

Comment: These files are in a (Attribute-Relation File Format) ARFF, the usual syntax for such files are described like this: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html 

the thing is that the files provided to me lacked the commas in the values of the @DATA in each ARFF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this search/replace:

search: `(?:\G(?!^)|^@DATA\R)[^ ]+\K[ ]`

replace: `,`

pattern details:

```
(?:         # non-capturing group
    \G      # anchor for the position of the last match
    (?!^)   # not at the start of a line
  |         # OR
    ^       # start of a line
    @DATA
    \R      # any newline sequence
)          
[^ ]+       # one or more characters that are not a space
\K          # discards all on the left from the match result
[ ]         # a space
```

To deal with several consecutive lines of datas and to stop at the first blank line, you need to change the pattern to:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^@DATA\R)[^\n ]+(?:\R[^\n ]+)?\K[ ]
```

Comment: @SoulDev: Thanks, but before accepting my answer, are you sure that this fits your requirements (test it carefully).

Comment: I have tested it with a single file, so far so good, i will perform the replacement with the whole fileset and test it in the further stage of my project, and ill let you know if everything is OK

Comment: There's a problem though, right now each file ends with a space, so every file after the replacement ends with a comma in the end of the final line....any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: @SoulDev: try to add `(?!\z)` or perhaps `(?!$)` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: tried with (?!$), so far so good, i'll let you know when it finish replacing all the files to check if it's ok

Comment: Thank you again, everything is ok now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex replacement (please note there is a literal space at the end of the pattern):

```
(?:^@DATA|\G(?!^))\K([\s\S]*?) (?!$)
```

And replace with `,$1`

[image]

And after replacement:

[image]

Comment: My current solution does not replace the final space.